# How to see what type of line endings are already in git repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, line-endings

First of all, I'm not asking what does it mean or how to change it. The thing what interest me most is: how can I see what's already in repo? What type of line endings.

I have my repositories on github and bitbucket.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 64):

You can use this command:

```
git ls-files --eol
```

It will output one line per file with the following information:

```
i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text=auto eol=lf   file.txt
```

In that example, `i/lf` means that the file uses `lf` in the index, and `w/crlf` means it uses `crlf` in the working directory.

Comment: Does the index reflect what's stored in the repository?

Answer (score 17):

To tell what line endings a file in the repository is using, use `git show` to extract the file's contents.  This will give you the contents *without changing the line endings*.

If you were to look at the files in your local working directory, as in one of the other answers, that only tells you what line endings are in the checked out working directory.  Git can, and on Windows usually will, change the line endings when files are checked out and reverse the change when they are committed.  So you will see CR-LF in the working directory even though the data in the repository uses LF.

Using `git show` or `git cat-file -p` will bypass this conversion.

The output of git show can be piped to file to have it automatically detect the line ending type.
E.x.:

```
git show HEAD:file.c | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

You can change the revision from `HEAD` to something else to see what the line endings were on an older revision.  For instance to see if they have changed.

Answer (score 12):

Download the repository source code as a `.zip` file. Use Notepad++ to check the files after enabling:

```
View->Show Symbol->Show End Of Line setting
```

Comment: What if one uses macos, is there an alternative to notepad++

Answer (score 5):

Line endings are an attribute of *files*, not repositories (and technically they can even be mixed within the same file). To see what type of line endings a particular file has you can use something like the `file` command on a Linux system (which should also work on OSX):

```
$ file some-file.txt
some-file.txt: ASCII text
```

This indicates that the line endings match the system default, so in my case it would be unix line endings. Windows line endings would show up like this:

```
$ file some-file.txt
some-file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Alternatively, open the file in a decent text-editor. Most will have a way to show you the line ending style. For example, Emacs shows

```
U(DOS)
```

in the modeline for the second example above, indicating CRLF ("DOS") line endings. Most other editors will have something similar.

If you want to see the `core.autocrlf` setting for a particular repository, run `git config core.autocrlf` inside it. You'll get back the value it's set to, or nothing if it is unset. These settings are local to the repository (i.e. not shared with GitHub, Bitbucket, or other users' local copies).

You might also want to inspect the repository's [`.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), if either exists. The former is stored as a regular file in the repository, so would be shared with other people, and the latter is specific to your local repository.

Comment: What do you mean by "Line endings are an attribute of files"? Do you mean that line endings is a kind of meta data of the file and is stored with the file?

Comment: @Gab是好人, no. Line endings aren't metadata; they're regular data. They're not normally displayed, but they're otherwise just like regular characters. My point is that asking, "what line endings are in this repository?" doesn't make much sense because different files, and even different lines within files, could use different line endings. It's like asking, "does my repository use uppercase or lowercase letters?"

Comment: caveat: you have to have `core.autocrlf = false` before you clone the repo. Otherwise, your local files may not match what's actually in the remote repo.

Comment: Line ending are metadata in git.  `gitattributes` stores an `eol` attribute, among others, for files in the repository.  This attribute is data about the file and not the data in the file itself.  That's metadata.  There is no attribute for uppercase or lowercase, nor will git convert the case of a file on check-in or check-out, so that is not comparable.

Comment: @TrentP, [line endings are characters in files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation). Consider (a) that they still exist even if there is no `.gitattributes` file present, and (b) that one single file can contain both Unix-style and Windows-style line endings at the same time. Git can _change them_ if you want it to, but that doesn't mean they're simply metadata. I'm not sure why you're bringing up upppercase and lowercase... that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: If there are no gitattributes files, then the eol attribute is in the "Unspecified" state.  The metadata, indicating the line ending mode the file is in, is still present.  You're only looking at the data in the file.  But there is more.  Git does store metadata.  And some of the metadata controls line endings.  Think of it as the repository object has data indicating a line should end, but the meta-data controls what characters are created to do that.  Allowing both kinds of line endings is a possible state.  As to uppercase and lowercase, read the 2nd comment, you brought that up.

Comment: @TrentP, and if the `eol` attribute is unspecified, and `autocrlf` and whatever other related settings aren't enabled, the data in the file is all there is. Try committing a file with mixed line endings and then cloning that repository. Again, yes, Git _can_ change the file endings in the working copy. But as far as I know, this is not default behaviour. It certainly isn't on Linux. I'm still not clear on what point you're making, unless it's that I should have expanded the last two paragraphs in my answer.